# I don't understand some parts of the code in the search in linked list

Tags: c

I wrote a linked list and I don't understand how to realize a search element in the linked list.

I understand the first part of the code, but not the part that starts with `if(found == true)`.

Thank you in advance if anyone decides to respond.

```
struct test_struct
{
    int val;
    struct test_struct *next;
};

struct test_struct *head = NULL;
struct test_struct *curr = NULL;

struct test_struct* create_list(int val)
{
    ...
}

struct test_struct *add_to_list(int val, bool add_to_end)
{
    ...
}

struct test_struct* search_in_list(int val, struct test_struct **prev)  
{
    struct test_struct *ptr = head;  
    struct test_struct *tmp = NULL;  
    bool found = false;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (ptr->val == val)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = ptr; // here tmp play role of previous pointer  
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    if (true == found)
    {
        if (prev)
            *prev = tmp;
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is incomplete and hence cannot be understood.

Comment: @Armali  i add some line of the code

Comment: `head` is never defined. `temp` is never defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `test_struct` is as following:

```
struct test_struct
{  
    int val;  
    struct test_struct *next;  
};
```

I also assume that your `head` is declared somewhere in your code as following:

```
struct test_struct *head;
```

and that your linked list is filled somewhere.

In your search function, you need to use the `val` attribute that you set, which is the value you are looking for. In the code you posted, it's not used anywhere. Also, there are some typos, using `temp` instead of `tmp`.

```
struct test_struct* search_in_list(int val, struct test_struct **prev) {
    struct test_struct *ptr = head;  
    struct test_struct *tmp = NULL;  
    bool found = false;

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (ptr->val == val) { /* val and not data */
            found = true;
            break;
        } else {
            ptr = tmp; /* tmp and not temp */
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    if (found == true) {
        if (prev)
            *prev = tmp; /* tmp and not temp */
        return ptr;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

In this function, the `prev` attribute is set to `tmp` at the end of the research. It means that **it saves the previous element of the linked list** compared to the one that was researched. Keep this only if you have a use for it!

Comment: thanks. but I don't understand why we write prev in the round brackets, and why we don't write curly brackets after if in the case? ``` if (found == true) {
        if (prev)
            *prev = tmp; /* tmp and not temp */
            return ptr;}```

Comment: curly brackets are optional when there is only one instruction in the "if" block. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901919/when-can-i-omit-curly-braces-in-c

Comment: but what means prev in curly brackets?

Comment: I think it's to make sure that the "prev" param is set when the function is called. This way, the "prev" param is optional, and it will be set to the tmp value only if it has been set in the function call.

Comment: thank so much, but i have another question,. so, for what it is used here  pointer to pointer : struct test_struct **prev?

Comment: I invite you to read this thread, that should help you understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698317/pointers-as-function-arguments-in-c Understanding pointers is a complex subject in C and cannot be explained with only a comment

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if that answered your question properly. Have a good day :)

Comment: I changed the code. I looked at the output. And I came to the conclusion that this is the part when         if(found== true...     and so on         is very important in finding the item! But why? Maybe these lines of code are needed to check? What do you think?